# makefile error: make: *** No rule to make target `omp.h' ; with OpenMP

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, openmp

all, I was compiling a C program with OpenMP. It's my first time to use makefile. When excuting "make", the gcc reports the error make: *** No rule to make target `omp.h', needed by`smooth.o'.  Stop. However the omp.h is in the /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include/omp.h , I am wondering how to fix it. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS = -fopenmp

all: smooth

smooth: smooth.o ompsooth.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o smooth smooth.o ompsmooth.o

ompsmooth.o: ompsmooth.c assert.h stdio.h stdlib.h omp.h ompsmooth.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) ompsmooth.c

smooth.o: smooth.c ompsmooth.h omp.h stdio.h stdlib.h string.h sys/types.h sys/stat.h     fcntl.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) smooth.c

clean:

    rm *.o
    rm smooth
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're expecting your standard header files to change, the simplest solution is just to remove them from the prerequisite list(s).

If you don't want to do the above, then you'll either need to specify the complete path to `omp.h`, or use the [`VPATH`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search) mechanism.

Comment: So, just like this?ompsmooth.o: ompsmooth.c 
 gcc $(CFLAGS) ompsmooth.c

smooth.o: smooth.c 
 gcc $(CFLAGS) smooth.c

Comment: what ever started this practice anyhow? the old X sources were even worse.

Comment: You got it. If the header files do change, then make won't know it should rebuild your source, but so it goes. A variety of build tools know how to automatically scan your .c file and create header dependencies for you, but not the default make you get with Linux. If you prefer to get gung-ho about it, you can find a way to twist old make's arm into doing this for you: http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html

Comment: @Robert: Sort of.  You'll probably want to retain the dependency on **your** header files (ompsmooth.h, etc.), otherwise stuff won't be recompiled if you change them.  On an unrelated note, you can simplify the rule with *automatic variables*: `gcc $(CFLAGS) $<`.

Comment: @technosaurus: What practice?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: using individual headers as dependencies.  I get wanting to rebuild if they change, but there has to be a better way... $INC_PATH/*.h maybe? ... or just omission.  The old xfree86 sources used makedeps to add a ton of header dependencies to each object, some of which are unnecessary and caused build failure for no reason.

Comment: @technosaurus, this style makes sense for complex pieces of code with constantly evolving data structures and many things implemented as macros or static functions in the headers. XFree86 sounds like a good candidate for being such kind of code. Nowadays generation of monstrous Makefiles with huge header dependency lists is simply automated by `GNU autotools`.