# How to install C++ dependencies "from source" for a Python package on Mac OS?

Tags: python, c++, macos, installation

There is a Github repo containing Python "bindings" for a C++ library that I am interested in playing with. The README has abundant information about how to install the C++ library on Linux like machines, but no information about how to do so with a mac OS.

I have also opened up an issue requesting the README installation instructions include mac OS-specific installs in addition to linux. There hasn't been any activity on that issue.

Here are the two repos:

- (Python) https://github.com/asiffer/python3-libspot
- (C++) https://github.com/asiffer/libspot

Since the C++ package isn't available for installing via Brew/pip/anaconda, I'm not sure how to get going.

#### What I've Tried:

I have tried `./configure`, and `make`. There is no `./configure` file.

To address the lack of `./configure`,  read about a tool called `autoconf` which supposedly generates `./configure` for you. I installed it with `brew`, but am not sure what arguments to pass it. These docs were pretty hard to understand: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Making-configure-Scripts.html

Just using `make` results in the error clang: `error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`That sent me down a whole different rabbit hole which had me adding lines to the Makefile:

```
CPP = /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -fopenmp
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib

omp_hello: omp_hello.c
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

That felt dangerous because I have no idea what any of that stuff means. Plus it resulted in a new error: `*** missing separator.  Stop.`

So then I read that's probably due to using "soft" tabs instead of "hard" tabs which can be identified using `cat -e -t -v makefile_name`. I found the one line where a "hard" tab was missing (the indented line above) and inserted it. This resulted in a new error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `omp_hello.c', needed by `omp_hello'.  Stop.
```

Next, following the advice of Yang Yushi and his follow on comments, I changed lines 39 and 40 according to his answer, plus added the locations of some additional files to the `CXXFLAGS` variable:

```
-I//opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/11.0.1/include 
-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/11.0.1/lib
```

And this got me a little further. Next, OSX didn't like where this script was trying to install, as explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33314242/3696204). So I changed these two lines in the makefile which seemed to dictate install location:

```
INSTALL_HEAD_DIR = $(DESTDIR)/usr/include/libspot
INSTALL_LIB_DIR = $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib
```

to

```
INSTALL_HEAD_DIR = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/include/libspot
INSTALL_LIB_DIR = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib
```

And that indeed got me a little farther. Next I ran into an error complaining about the flat `-t` at these lines in the makefile:

```
@install -t $(INSTALL_LIB_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)/*.so
@install -t $(INSTALL_HEAD_DIR) $(INC_DIR)/*.h
```

So I deleted those flags, which then resulted in this error:

```
Checking the headers installation directory (/usr/local/include/libspot)
Checking the library installation directory (/usr/local/lib)
Installing the shared library (libspot.so)
install: /usr/local/lib: Inappropriate file type or format
```

For which I can find no reading material and have no clue how to fix. Any further assistance appreciated.

Here's a list of SO and other resources I've perused trying to answer this question:

- [Enable OpenMP support in clang in Mac OS X (sierra & Mojave)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra-mojave/48746939#48746939)
- [makefile error: make: *** No rule to make target `omp.h' ; with OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924683/makefile-error-make-no-rule-to-make-target-omp-h-with-openmp)
- [makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)
- http://www.idryman.org/blog/2016/03/10/autoconf-tutorial-1/
- https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Making-configure-Scripts.html
- https://developer.gnome.org/anjuta-build-tutorial/stable/create-autotools.html.en

#### My Question

How do I proceed.

If you know how to do this, could you also include a brief explanation of the concepts behind each step? I'd be happy to learn a little instead of just copying and pasting commands in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

### Compile the C++ source code with Apple Clang

I downloaded the [prjoect (libspot)](https://github.com/asiffer/libspot) and successfully compiled it on my Mac. I change two lines (39 and 40) in the Makefile to make it work. (Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60564952/4116538))

```
CC = clang++  # change from g++ to default Apple clang
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp  -lomp  # additional flags
```

You should get the binary file by just type `make` with a "correct" Makefile.

(If you see something like "cant find omp.h", add `-I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include` to the `CXXFLAGS`.)

---

### For the Question

The error message in the updated question description

> make: *** No rule to make target `omp_hello.c', needed by` omp_hello'.  Stop.

is telling us that the file `omp_hello.c` is missing. The Makefile is written to compile the source code `omp_hello.c` to an executable binary file `omp_hello`. If I have the C source file (`omp_hello.c`), the Makefile will allow me to compile by just typing

```sh
make
```

instead of

```sh
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang \
-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -fopenmp \
-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib \
omp_hello.c -o omp_hello
```

This is just a normal compile process, it has nothing to do with Python. The error message is saying the source code to be compiled (`omp_hello.c`) is missing.

---

It looks like this is a small project with custom Makefile. Normally you compile the code with just `make`. The error you got seems to suggest the lack of llvm. You may want to try install llvm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48746939/4116538).

Comment: Thank you, but I made sure I have `llvm` installed as well as `libomp`. I have already seen that answer.

Comment: Maybe try to change `CPP = /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang` to `CPP = /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that still leaves me with `*** No rule to make target `omp_hello.c', needed by `omp_hello'.  Stop.`

Comment: Oh sorry this is saying you don't have the file `omp_hello.c`. Do you see the file in your current folder? (Also this is actually a C file not C++ so maybe you want to change `CPP` back to `CPP = /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clan`...)

Comment: Hi @rocksNwaves it might also be helpful if you share the link to the repository that you are playing with.

Comment: Hi @rocksNwaves I compiled the project on my Mac, and I modified its Makefile a little bit. I posted my method in the answer. Hopefully it would help.

Comment: when I see the `omp.h` error, should I add that flag in addition to what is already there or replace what is already there?

Comment: Add it to the end, something like `CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp  -lomp -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228174/discussion-between-rocksnwaves-and-yang-yushi).

Answer (score 0):

Usually it comes to running `brew install <your C++ package>` or downloading the source code to some directory and running a set of commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

While usually it works, some packages can not be installed on Mac since their maintainers did not prepare configuration for Mac.

Comment: There is no `./configure` file in the repo I cloned from GitHub. I tried just using `make` but got `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`

Comment: If you fail on the first try, I suggest taking other path. Try installing Linux as VM. It will probably be much faster.